# If/Else statement nested in While loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

(I am very new to JavaScript and am writing this to try and get used to using it a bit more - which is why I'm using an object to store usernames and passwords. I'm learning this as part of an apprenticeship but this is during my own time to further my knowledge on JS)
I have tried writing a small piece of code that should ask the user to enter a username, which will be cross-checked against the property names in the object "*userNames*". The user is then asked to enter a password for this user which is then checked against the password set as the value of the corresponding property with the right username. 
I feel as though part of the problem is to do with me trying to use the variable "*enteredPassword*" (set to the user's input for the password as a method) of "*userNames*". 
If the username or password are incorrect after 3 attempts then I'd like the window to close.
my text editor is saying that the If statement is missing a branch and I'm not sure if this is affecting whether this works or not.

```js
var userNames = {Tom:"PassW0rd", Bill:"Apples40C0lander", Ryan:"M1911p4ck4ge"};
var Greeting = "Insert Username:";

var i = 0;
while (i < 3)
{
    var enteredUserName = prompt(Greeting);
    var enteredPassword = prompt("enter password for " + enteredUserName);

    if ((userNames.hasOwnProperty(enteredUserName)) && (userNames.enteredUserName==enteredPassword)) {
        alert("Welcome");
        break;
    } else {
        alert("incorrect Username or Password");
        alert("");
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
        i++
    }}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the `if`-statement

Comment: you are not incrementing i, so i < 3 is always true and you are creating an infinite loop

Comment: The code does not compile because of the `semicolon` after the `if-statement`. The semicolon closes the whole `if`, so the `else` does not belong to it anymore -> syntax error. It gets interpreted as the ' short-writing' of `if`s with only one command. The syntax is this: `if (expression) command;`. You see, no `{` and `}` needed if you only use one command. A single `;` without anything else gets interpreted as an `empty command`, so `if (expression) ; ` completes the `if`.

Comment: I do not see `i++` anywhere, so the loop is infinite. Think about using `for` loop instead of `while`. Also, the `continue`(iterate) probably should be `break`(quit).

Comment: Thank you, I have made these changes, so now the dialog boxes do appear however even if I enter a correct username and password the loop continues.

Comment: must be break statement some where instead of continue right?

Comment: I've changed the 'continue' to 'break', however it still runs through the rest of the loop - which i think is to do with the "userNames.enteredUserName==enteredPassword" line

Answer (score 0):

A simple change is enough here : 
`userNames[enteredUserName]`.
In `JavaScript`, `Object` can also accessed like `array`.
If you use `userNames.enteredUserName` , then it will check `{enteredUserName:somevalue}` (ie, `enteredUserName` will be considered as a `String`. but if you use it as `userNames[enteredUserName]` , then `enteredUserName` will be considered as variable and index to the `Object`.
Try below snippet.

```js
var userNames = {Tom:"PassW0rd", Bill:"Apples40C0lander", Ryan:"M1911p4ck4ge"};
var Greeting = "Insert Username:";

var i = 0;
while (i < 3)
{
    var enteredUserName = prompt(Greeting);
    var enteredPassword = prompt("enter password for " + enteredUserName);

    if ((userNames.hasOwnProperty(enteredUserName)) && (userNames[enteredUserName]==enteredPassword)) {
        alert("Welcome");
        break;
    } else {
        alert("incorrect Username or Password");
        alert("");
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
        window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();
        i++
    }}
```